# How to generate a Windows DLL with static library linking on CMake

Tags: dll, cmake

I am trying to make DLL using static library using CMake, but couldn't resolve the unresolved external reference issue.  I checked similar Q&A, but couldn't resolve the issue.. 
I'd appreciate your any comment.

```
#---------------------------------------------- <br>
include(GenerateExportHeader) <br>
add_subdirectory("third_party") &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;  # Generates 3rd party static, DLL both <br>
add_library(my_target_dll &nbsp; SHARED &nbsp; my_src.cpp &nbsp; my_src_2.cpp &nbsp; export_lib.def) &emsp; <br>
target_link_libraries(my_target_dll &nbsp; third_party-static) &emsp; &emsp;  # For referring 3rd party static lib <br>
generate_export_header(my_target_dll) <br>
#---------------------------------------------- <br>
```

I defined export_lib.def for all my DLL function's name demangling. 
"my_src.cpp" refers third_party-static function name, like a func_a, func_b. 
The problem is, linker shows that my_src.obj tries to refer __imp__func_a and __imp__func_b, not func_a and func_b.
If I try to make binary, not DLL, there is no problem.  I suspect my DLL generation option changed my DLL's static lib reference as DLL type also...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found the reason...
Generally, 3rd party header is defined as below, without regarding static / dynamic :

#ifdef DLL_EXPORT 
#define DLLExport __declspec(dllexport) 
#else 
#define DLLExport __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

But, when using the static library, this shall not be used.
Or, DLLExport shall be defined as null.